# передача в функцию переменного количества позиционных аргументов

Tags: python

Есть функция, в которую передается список со строками подписей кнопок, которые выводятся в чат-боте Телеграм. Сами кнопки добавляются с помощью метода add() класса ReplyKeyboardMarkup.

Проблема в том, что если вызывать метод add() последовательно для добавления каждой кнопки (variant 2 В коде), то кнопки добавляются просто в колонку - одна над другой, а если передать все созданные кнопки сразу как позиционные аргументы, то кнопки выглядят как надо - располагаются пропорционально.
Я конечно выкрутился через подсчёт количества элементов в списке и дальше через elif (variant 1 в коде): но уверен что это говнокод и должен быть в Пайтоне какой-то более гибкий и изящный метод.

```
 def create_reply_buttons(buttons_list):
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True, selective=False,
                                   one_time_keyboard=False,
                                   input_field_placeholder='')
b = [types.KeyboardButton(buttons_list[i]) for i in range(len(buttons_list))]
variant = 1
if variant == 1:
    __b: int = len(buttons_list)
    if __b==0:
        return
    elif __b==1:
        markup.add(b[0])
    elif __b==2:
        markup.add(b[0], b[1])
    elif __b == 3:
        markup.add(b[0], b[1], b[2])
elif variant == 2:
   for i in buttons_list:
        itembtn = types.KeyboardButton(i)
        markup.add(itembtn)
```

Comment: `markup.add(*b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. Вызов с переменным количеством аргументов

```
from aiogram import *

def create_reply_buttons(*buttons_list): # <----
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        row_width=2,
        resize_keyboard=True,
        selective=False,
        one_time_keyboard=False,
        input_field_placeholder=''
    )
    buttons = [types.KeyboardButton(btn) for btn in buttons_list]
    markup.add(*buttons)

create_reply_buttons(1, 2, 3, 4) # <----
```

2. Вызов с переменной длинной списка:

```
from aiogram import *

def create_reply_buttons(buttons_list): # <----
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        row_width=2,
        resize_keyboard=True,
        selective=False,
        one_time_keyboard=False,
        input_field_placeholder=''
    )
    buttons = [types.KeyboardButton(btn) for btn in buttons_list]
    markup.add(*buttons)

create_reply_buttons([1, 2, 3, 4]) # <----
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Именно то, что нужно было.